Woocommerce how to utilize proceed_to_checkout_button
I have been working on trying to not allow the user to be directed to the shopping cart page via the "proceed_to_checkout" button unless they have clicked on a disclaimer checkbox. I want to show the "proceed_to_checkout" ONLY if the user has clicked the corresponding checkbox. The proceed_to_cart seems to be an < a > tag, as shown below. I know how to show the checkbox when selected, but am having difficulty using jQuery to only show the proceed_to_checkout button/< a > tag unless the box has been checked.
Here is the proceed_to_checkout button:
<a href="https://nextdaygps.com/order-checkout-page/" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" style="pointer-events: auto; opacity: 1;"> Proceed to checkout</a>

Currently, I can show the disclaimer checkbox. However, the proceed_to_checkout button/tag automatically is still there on refresh, even with the blank checkbox.
Below is my code I have:
// WOOCMMERCE CHECKBOX PLUGIN
function cart_items_skus( $skus = array() ) {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        $skus[] = $item['data']->get_sku();
    }
    return $skus;
}

// ICG70_Rover
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'ICG70_Rover', 10 );
function ICG70_Rover() {

    // SKU product 
    $checkSKUs = ['3'];
    // Here, define the targeted product IDs
    $targeted_SKUs = $checkSKUs;

    // Check if any of the targeted products SKUs is in cart
    if ( array_intersect( $targeted_SKUs, cart_items_skus() ) ) {
        // Field attribute name (and ID)
        $field_slug = 'cart_disclaimer_cb';

        // Enqueue jQuery code
        wc_enqueue_js("const strPTC = '.checkout-button', btnPTC = $(strPTC), checkoutURL = btnPTC.prop('href');
        btnPTC.removeAttr('href').addClass('disabled');
        $(document.body).on('change', 'input[name={$field_slug}]', function(){
            $(this).prop('checked') ? 
            btnPTC.prop('href', checkoutURL).removeClass('disabled') :
            btnPTC.removeAttr('href').addClass('disabled');
        });");

        // Display the checkbox
        woocommerce_form_field( $field_slug, array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('form-row disclaimer-checkbox'), // CSS Class
            'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
            'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
            'required'      => true, // Mandatory or Optional
            'label'         => 'I have read and understood ICG70 Rover disclaimer.',  // Label and Link
        ));
    }
}


Instead of using a third party plugin to add the checkbox, I would rather use a custom template on the checkout page, which would give you more control over the functionality and the layout.  Also, I'd recommend asking this question on WordPress Stackexchange, not here.
